# Create an object that has a key where the value is an array

Tags: groovy

Basically, I want to somehow create a JSON object from a Groovy object. The Groovy object has key value pairs, and one of the values is a Groovy Array:

```
   import groovy.json.*

   // Imagine "handler" gets called somehow and an event gets passed to it.
   def handler(event) {
       def capabilitiesList = event.device.capabilities.findAll { attr -> attr.name != null }
       def json = new JsonBuilder({
           id event.deviceId
           displayName event.displayName
           value event.value
       })
   }

   log.debug capabilitiesList
   log.debug json.toPrettyString()
```

At this point, `json.toPrettyString()` gives me this:

```
   {
       "id": "asdfl469934623sdglsi3aqaq",
       "displayName": "Some Lightbulb",
       "value": "on"
   }
```

And `capabilitiesList` gives me this:

```
   ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"]
```

How can I add the `capabilitiesList` array to the Groovy object so it gets converted to JSON?

I can't seem to get anything to work; the only thing that does work is  this:

```
   // ...
   def json = new JsonBuilder({
       id event.deviceId
       displayName event.displayName
       value event.value
       capabilitiesList "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"
   })
   // ...
```

Which gives me this (correct) JSON output:

```
   {
       "id": "asdfl469934623sdglsi3aqaq",
       "displayName": "Some Lightbulb",
       "value": "on",
       "capabilitiesList": ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"]
   }
```

But that obviously isn't useful because it's hard coded. So I tried referencing the Array directly like this:

```
   // ...
   def capabilitiesList = event.device.capabilities.findAll { attr -> attr.name != null }
   def json = new JsonBuilder({
       id event.deviceId
       displayName event.displayName
       value event.value
       capabilitiesList capabilitiesList
   })
   // ...
```

But that breaks the `JsonBuilder` somehow, and it doesn't output anything.

I'm probably doing something really silly here but I can't quite figure out how to get this done. First time with Groovy as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Instead of `capabilities` in your last code snippet, use `capabilitiesList` a second time. The first time will be interpreted as the name of the JSON property; the second time will be interpreted as the Groovy list variable to be converted to a JSON list.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a mistake on my part. When I do what you describe above, it fails to output a string in `toPrettyString()`. :(

Comment: Hmmmm. Something strange is going on here. Try this: change the declaration from `def capabilitiesList` to `List<String> capabilitiesList` and tell me what happens.

Comment: Another thing to try: use the spread (`*`) operator inside `JsonBuilder`, like this: `capabilitiesList *capabilitiesList`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the builder DSL should work. For example:

```
List list = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']

def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

builder {
   id "asdfl469934623sdglsi3aqaq"
   displayName "Some Lightbulb"
   value "on"
   capabilitiesList list
}

println builder.toPrettyString()
```

prints

```
{
    "id": "asdfl469934623sdglsi3aqaq",
    "displayName": "Some Lightbulb",
    "value": "on",
    "capabilitiesList": [
        "Test1",
        "Test2",
        "Test3"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I have a list that is inside the `event` variable in my question example. Plugging that into the `builder` object does not work. Manually defining it defeats the whole purpose, since I want to use the list that's passed down from the `events` object. Thanks!